What is the value in Column Primereact
I need to create a function that deletes the product I selected in an expanding line in Primereact.
const actionProdutoBodyTemplate = (rowData: Sistema.DetalhePedidos) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Button icon="pi pi-trash" rounded severity="danger" className="mr-2" onClick={() => deletaProduto(rowData)} />
        </>
    );
};

in my deleteProduto function, I did a console.log(rowData) and the information I need comes (information about the product I selected, such as id, name, etc...)
However, when I add some parameters to the actionProdutoBodyTemplate call, the RowData value changes.
const rowExpansionTemplate = (data: Sistema.Produtos) => {
        // Filtrar os detalhes das vendas para mostrar apenas os detalhes da venda atual
        const detalhesDaVendaAtual = detalhesDasVendas.filter((detalhe: any) => data.detalhes.includes(detalhe.id));

        return (
            <div className="orders-subtable">
                <h5>Produtos da Venda de Código {data.id}</h5>
                <DataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum Produto na Venda" value={detalhesDaVendaAtual} responsiveLayout="scroll">
                    <Column header="Imagem" body={imageBodyTemplate}></Column>
                    <Column field="produto.nome" header="Produto" sortable></Column>
                    <Column field="quantidade" header="Quantidade" sortable></Column>
                    <Column field="produto.custo" header="Custo" sortable></Column>
                    <Column field="produto.peso" header="Peso" sortable></Column>
                    <Column field="produto.valor" header="Valor" sortable></Column>
                    <Column body={actionProdutoBodyTemplate} header="Ações" headerStyle={{ minWidth: '12rem' }}></Column>
                </DataTable>
            </div>
        );
    };


What value is passed to actionProdutoBodyTemplate when it has no parameters?
